# IF_NAMESIZE vs. IF_NAMESIZE+1

Tags: c, network-programming, posix

When I use `IF_NAMESIZE` (from [`net/if.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/net_if.h.html) in libc implementations) as array size, should I use it as it is or with `+ 1` for `\0` (null byte)?

```
char iface[IF_NAMESIZE];
```

or

```
char iface[IF_NAMESIZE + 1];
```

I see it using both ways across various open source projects.

Comment: [This POSIX reference of the `<net/if.h>` header file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/net_if.h.html) might be useful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Are you mad documentation is for weak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The  header shall define the following symbolic constant for
>   the length of a buffer containing an interface name (including the
>   terminating NULL character):
>
> IF_NAMESIZE Interface name length.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/net_if.h.html

So:

```
char iface[IF_NAMESIZE];
```

is enough

Comment: So do you think that + 1 is redundant or has different meaning? Just searching [`IF_NAMESIZE\s*\+ 1` in https://codesearch.debian.net/](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=IF_NAMESIZE%5Cs*%5C%2B+1&perpkg=1) shows many projects including [python3](http://sources.debian.net/src/python3.6/3.6.2-2/Modules/socketmodule.c/#L6250) or [lvvm](http://sources.debian.net/src/llvm-toolchain-snapshot/1:5.0~svn305653-1/compiler-rt/test/msan/if_indextoname.cc/#L14) or even [glibc itself](http://sources.debian.net/src/glibc/2.24-16/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ifaddrs.c/#L69).

Comment: Another example of libc implementation [uclibc](http://sources.debian.net/src/uclibc/1.0.20-2/libc/inet/ifaddrs.c/?hl=62#L62), again in `ifaddrs.c`.

Comment: @pevik According to the documentation this is redundant.

Comment: Better be extra safe (at the cost of 1 byte) than reading and interpreting the documentation !

Comment: @pmg "including the terminating NULL character" is not clear enough for you, you call that "interpreting the documentation" ?!?